# Embed Form In Header

Tags: custom-header

I'm using WordPress theme Twenty Ninteen and trying to make a travel blog with the help of travel affiliate API get from Travelpayouts.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="//www.travelpayouts.com/widgets/920a6b8c6fc20070013d2e04f690210d.js?v=1649" async></script>
```

This is form code to display on pages/post, if I use on any post on page code working fine but I need to add this code in the header to display like.

[image: form image]

I try to use the plugin for header & footer to paste the code & display but via plugin code working in the footer but in header nothing display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit `header.php` of your theme and insert the script there right after the site navigation.

> I try to use the plugin for header & footer to paste the code & display but via plugin code working in the footer but in header nothing display.

Plugins fail to insert this in header because these plugins use `wp-header` hook which output in `<head>` tag and not in the `<body>` tag, so the output is not visible.

While those plugins which uses `wp_footer` hook outputs everything within `<body>` tag, so the output is visible.

Comment: thanks its working and i got it one that how can i use in header.
i have two questions there.

1. How can i be specific on some pages to display
2. Once i click search it goes to another page i want to display the result in the body.

Comment: For display on specific pages use conditional template tag  `is_page()` [DOCS](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).  For result display on same consult the documentation of affiliate API.